# can only open application launcher when application launcher settings is in focus

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I cannot open the Application Launcher by clicking on the icon.

I cannot open the Application Launcher by using the assigned shortcut key [Alt+F1].

When the "Application Launcher Settings" app is open AND has focus, then, and only then can I open the Application Launcher by clicking on it or by using the shortcut key.

This started happening with an update sometime in the past few weeks.

- Kubuntu
- KDE Plasma 5.18.5
- KDE Frameworks 5.68.0
- Qt 5.12.8
- Kernel 5.4.0-42-generic
- 64-bit